# Destroy all controller action in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have a `Notification` model. All in all, this model is unimportant and is just to notify the user. I have no reason to keep this data.

The user can clear their notifications one by one via AJAX, and that part works fine.

I want to give the user a "Delete All" option. Much like in Android's notification center.

Is the best way to do this a customer controller action? Or would I use the delete controller and pass the user id and some sort of flag for delete all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would post in `destroy_all_notifications_path`, without any id, and on the controller destroy all notifications of the logged user.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare a new action in your Notification controller :

```
 def destroy_all
   @user.notifications.each(&:destroy)
 end
```

Then add it to your routes

```
 map.resources :users do |user|
   user.resources :notifications, :collection => { :destroy_all => :delete }
 end
```

Don't forget to check if @user is current_user !

In your view, use a link to destroy.

```
 <%= link_to_remote :destroy_all_notifications_user_path(current_user) %>
```

Comment: This really shouldn't exist as a sub-route of `users`. There is no reason a user ever needs to post back to *another* user's destroy-all route. It should *always* be the currently logged-in user whose notifications are being affected.

Comment: This behavior is useful for some administration... You just have to check if @user is current_user or if current_user is admin.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I stumbled upon this myself and here is how I solved this. So first of all, the collection of user notifications can be modeled as a RESTful resource. However, this resource cannot have an id and also a user can have only one collection of notifications, not many. That is why I would model this as a singular resource like this:

```
resources :user do
  resource :notifications, only: :destroy
end
```

This would give me the RESTful route `DELETE /users/:user_id/notifications`. Now, the problem with this is that, by default, Rails will assign this route to `NotificationsController#destroy`. Since you have already assigned this action to destroying individual notification, you'll have to create a separate controller for the resource "user_notifications".

I'd create a folder `users` under `app/controllers` and in it I'd create `notifications_controller.rb`. Then in this controller, I'd implement the `destroy` action. Finally, in the routes, I'll need to specify the controller like this:

```
resources :user do
  resource :notifications, only: :destroy, controller: 'users/notifications'
end
```